# Error of "Command 'pip' not found" when trying to install requirements.txt

Tags: django, linux, git

I'm trying to do: pip install -r requirements.txt on an AWS server. I recently pulled a git commit.

I get this error:

```
Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-pip
```

So I tried entering:

```
sudo apt install python-pip install -r requirements.txt

and then

sudo apt install python-pip -r requirements.txt
```

But both attempts gave me this error:

```
E: Command line option 'r' [from -r] is not understood in combination with the other options.
```

What is the correct command to install this? Thank you.

Comment: The error is telling you how to **install** pip not how to run it. You need to run `sudo apt install python-pip` to install pip and __then__ run `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing multiple commands.

1. `apt` ; It is Debian's package manager. It has nothing to do with python packages. You install pip through apt. There are also other ways of doing it.
2. `pip` : As understood it is python package manager. You can install dependencies for your project by listing them in requirements.txt.

The correct way would be :

```
sudo apt install python-pip
#install from a file requirements.txt:
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
#install as a user :
pip install -U -r requirements.txt
```